# ExtJS 6: Populate a form with checkboxes using Ext.data.Model and loadRecord method

Tags: javascript, forms, client, extjs6

I'm trying to populate a form with checkboxes using JavaScript object and Ext.data.Model. With textField form the following code works fine:

```
// text is an array with text values
var currentForm = {
                  "name_value1": text[0],
                  "name_value2": text[1],
               };


Ext.define('CurrentFormModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name_value1', 
             'name_value2', 
            ]
    });


var Get_textFieldForm = textFieldForm.getForm();
Get_textFieldForm.loadRecord(new CurrentFormModel(currentForm));
```

How can I succeed that with a checkbox form ? I tried the following:

```
// text[2][i] is an array with the checked values
var checkFormObj = {
       "checkboxGroupName": [text[2][0], text[2][1]]
       }

 Ext.define('CheckboxModel', {
                 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                 fields: [{name: 'checkboxGroupName', type: 'boolean'}]
               });
 var Get_CheckboxForm = CheckboxForm_name.getForm();
 Get_CheckboxForm.loadRecord(new CheckboxModel(checkFormObj));
```

My checkbox form:

```
CheckboxForm_name = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Checkbox form',
        collapsible: true,
        collapsed: true,
        items: [{
               xtype: 'checkboxfield',
               name: 'checkboxGroupName',
               boxLabel: 'Checkbox1',
               inputValue: 'checkbox_1'
               }, {
               xtype: 'checkboxfield',
               name: 'checkboxGroupName',
               boxLabel: 'Checkbox2',
               inputValue: 'checkbox_2'
               }]
       });
```

But nothing happens. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. There is no need to define an object with fields nor extend the Ext.data.Model class in order to include the fields.
The following code populates the checkboxes form.

```
var CheckboxModel = new Ext.data.Model({
                <name>: [<inputValue>, // the input values of checkboxes
                         <inputValue>
                        ]
              });

var Get_CheckboxForm = CheckboxForm_name.getForm();
Get_CheckboxForm.loadRecord(CheckboxModel);
```